# What table keeps a guid of the record in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

By using that  method Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId() I can get a GUID of entity record.

However, I'd not found it in organizationname_MSCRM database

Does anyone know where can I check it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of entities in CRM DB has two tables, for example, [ContactBase] and [ContactExtensionBase]. So, you can check it in one of them - column **ContactId**.

To find correct name of ID column that you are searching, check entity metadata page - [example for contact entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328530.aspx) - and search for *Uniqueidentifier*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used Contact only for example. What entity you are using?

Comment: account's entity, the method is returned guid like {XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} and the Account is liek that template XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: So, the question is, where is account Guid in CRM database, right?

Comment: @ lazarus yes, exactly

Comment: Guid of account entity is in table [AccountBase], and the name of the column is [AccountId]

Comment: it's recommended to use filtered views instead the tables, so it's better to look for [FilteredAccount] instead of [AccountBase]

Comment: `SELECT * FROM organizationname_MSCRM database.dbo.FilteredAccount WHERE AccountId = 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';`